# Modify Android Slideshow to accept String array input in R.drawable?

Tags: java, android, slideshow

There is an excellent piece of simple Android Slideshow code here http://moorandroid.blogspot.com/p/image-slide-show.html which 
works perfectly if using R.drawable, but I have a set of images obtained from Cursor _DATA and need to know how to convert 
these to fit, as they are in a String[] array, not Integer[]?

```
 Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4
 };

 String[] images = {
        "/storage/extSdCard/image1.jpg",
        "/storage/extSdCard/image2.jpg",
        "/storage/extSdCard/image3.jpg",
        "/storage/extSdCard/image4.jpg"
 };
 ....
 private void animatedSlideShow() {
    slideShow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slider1);
    slideShow.setImageResource(imageIDs[index%imageIDs.length]);  //--- Need to modify
    index ++;
    Animation showImage = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this,true);
    slideShow.startAnimation(showImage);
 }
```

My question is then: how to I adapt the slideShow.setImageResource to accept a string array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to I adapt the slideShow.setImageResource to accept a string
>   array?

As `images` Array contains path of images which is inside sdcard and `imageIDs` contains id's of images which is inside application drawable folder.

To show images from `images` :

**1.** Read  image from sdcard as file:

```
File imgFile = new  File(index%images.length]);
```

**2.** Get `Bitmap` using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` from `imgFile` :

```
Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

**3.** Call `setImageBitmap` of ImageView to show image in ImageView :

```
slideShow.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it works fine but I am still seeing _no images_, although _Logcat_ shows the correct path of each sequential one, and Android Studio (Device Monitor) also shows the files in the correct place, ie /storage/extSdCard/filename.jpg, etc; but no images appear on my device!

Comment: @Archdeacon: testing on real device?

Comment: Yes (Samsung SM-G313M); but it now only works if I change _.getAbsolutePath_ to _.getCanonicalPath_! No idea why, but could this be related to the R/W restrictions Google have put on KitKat (4.4.2) which I have on this device?

Answer (score 1):

Use [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) like:

```
Drawable[] imagesResources= new Drawable[imageIDs.length];
for(int drawableId : imageIDs){
    imagesResources[0] = getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageId);
}
TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
slideShow.setImageDrawable(transition);
transition.startTransition(1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Drawables to slideShow using this way :

```
for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        Drawable myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), images[i]);
        slideShow.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding an explanation